# How to detach a input element from Place autosuggestion in Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have attached an input element with Google places autosuggestion service and it works perfect for me. How can I detach the element in JavaScript or jQuery so that after detaching when I type into the box I don't get autosuggestions?

I have used following code for attaching the input element:

```
var options  = {types: ['establishment']};
var input    = document.getElementById('businessname');
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

I tried deleting autocomplete object. But, still I was getting suggestions when I type into the box named businessname.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I am really sorry for making a duplicate post. Really appreciate your quick response.

Comment: No need to excuse, you wouldn't have asked this when you knew where to find the answer.